# Multilingual application using resources TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, multilingual, typeinitializeexception

I've two Reources in Properties/String/ (cs-CZ.resx;default.resx)

I set it up this way:

```
    internal static System.Resources.ResourceManager strings;

    public static void SetLanguage(string culture)
    {
        if (culture == "cs-CZ")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
            strings = Properties.Strings.cs_CZ.ResourceManager;
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            strings = Properties.Strings._default.ResourceManager;
        }
    }
```

In Form constructor:

```
    SetLanguage("cs-CZ");
```

And then

```
    public static string Translate(string name)
    {
        return strings.GetString(name);
    }

mainStrip.Text = Translate("mainStrip");
```

But I'm getting TypeInitializationException. Whats wrong?

Comment: Can you post the exception details?

Comment: I'd like, but it just show only. That TypeInitializationException occured in SetLanguage method. I've tried put this `return Properties.Strings.cs_CZ.ResourceManager.GetString(name);` to Translate method. And comment out setlanguage method. It works now. So problem is in SetLanguage method.

Comment: Look at the InnerException to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

TypeInitializationException is caused mainly using private static constructor. Calling `SetLanguage` method will call this constructor and it thrown this exception. So create new Class for this or call constructor before this method.

Fxp. here it's nice example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/typeinitializationexception